Are model weights from a non-commercial project protected from commercial use with reverse engineered code?
According to this question, model weights are not copyrightable. Does this mean that the weights of a non-commercial open-source model could be used for commercial purposes, provided that the accompanying code was either derived from the paper or reverse-engineered?

If I understand the answer in the other question correctly, the weights are not protected at all, except perhaps as trade secrets (in which case you can't use them because you don't know them).

They're analogous with the formula for Coca Cola or KFC's secret recipe.

What is the license that gave you access?!

@Trish What do you mean by “the license that gave you access”?

Often, you agree to a contract by just getting access to code. Such ad an MIT license.
